# Index of a list view item in a group

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, listviewitem, listviewgroup

`ListViewItem.Index` property gets the zero-based index of the item within the `ListView` control.
Now I need index of certain item in a `ListViewGroup` , not the whole control. 
Is it possible?

Answer (score 5):

You can find its index within the group as such :

```
ListViewItem item = /* certain item in a ListviewGroup */;
var index = item.Group.Items.IndexOf(item);
```

Comment: @BehzadSedighzadeh When a post answers your question, you can mark it as accepted by click on check mark near the answer. *Accepting an answer is important as it both rewards posters for solving your problem and informs others that your issue is resolved.* You can read more about [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). I noticed that you haven't accepted an answer in all your previous questions, you can review them and mark some answers as accepted if they solved your problems :)